# KTPhotoBrowser push to KTTumbsViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use [KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser) to use its thumbnail view capabilities. I have some difficulties to push to the viewController that was derived from KTThumbsViewController. It seems the navigationController can only push to UIViewController:

```
- (void)showSDWebImageSample
{
KTThumbsViewController *newController = [[KTThumbsViewController alloc] init];        
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
}
```

and the header file for KTThumbsViewController includes:

```
@interface KTThumbsViewController : UIViewController <KTThumbsViewDataSource>
```

I grabbed the code from the provided sample. But it gives me the following runtime error:

-[KTThumbsViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8877130
2012-10-30 14:52:03.004 myCases_MD[36941:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[KTThumbsViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8877130'

Could anyone help me please?

Cheers,